# Using a DataContractSurrogate with WCF REST

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

How can I use a DataContractSurrogate for my WCF REST service (hosted using a WebServiceHostFactory)?

I don't see a way of adding one and even if I add a custom IOperationBehavior, the WebServiceHost automatically overwrites and ignores it.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the following two steps:

First, implement IDatacontractSurrogate interface:

```
class MySurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        //Implementation here
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        //Implementation here
    }

    //Implemenentation of the remaining methods...
}
```

Second, set your surrogate on the ServiceHost like this:

```
foreach (var endpoint in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints)
{
    foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
    {
         operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>().DataContractSurrogate = new MySurrogate();
    }
}
```

Remember to do this before you open your service host. Otherwise it may not work.

In case you're using IIS hosting and specifying the `WebServiceHostFactory` in an `.svc` file, then understandably, you don't have the opportunity set the surrogate. To overcome that, you have two options:

1. Create a custom service behavior attribute and set the surrogate in its `ApplyDispatchBehavior()` method. Once you place this attribute on your sevice, WCF will automatically execute this method and the surrogate will be set.
2. [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) your own custom service host by subclassing `WebServiceHost`. Then set the surrogate in its `ApplyConfiguration()` method. This too will have the same effect.

Comment: WebServiceHost doesn't listen to a custom DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior if you apply it. It ignores and overwrites it.

Comment: That's odd. The way I described above works perfectly in my case. Are you sure Jeff that you're setting the surrogate before the host is opened?

Comment: Hmmm, I'll certainly try it again...but I think this is a known issue... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working:  WCF 4.0 REST service hosted using a WebServiceHostFactory in IIS.

I used a custom attribute to inject my NHProxyDataContractSurrogate:

```
public class CanSerializeNHProxyAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription description, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime proxy)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription opDesc in description.Operations)
        {
            ApplyDataContractSurrogate(opDesc);
        }
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription description, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatch)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription opDesc in description.Operations)
        {
            ApplyDataContractSurrogate(opDesc);
        }
    }

    private static void ApplyDataContractSurrogate(OperationDescription description)
    {
        DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsOperationBehavior = description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        if (dcsOperationBehavior != null)
        {
            if (dcsOperationBehavior.DataContractSurrogate == null)
                dcsOperationBehavior.DataContractSurrogate = new NHProxyDataContractSurrogate();
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndPoint, BindingParameterCollection parameters) { }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndPoint) { }
}
```

And applied the custom attribute to my ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[CanSerializeNHProxy]
public interface IElementManager
{ ... }
```

I got a lot of useful info from these links:

[DataContractSurrogate MSDN page, pointing to custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[DataContractSurrogate implementation for serializing NHibernate proxy objects](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/nhusers@googlegroups.com/2010-02/msg00042.html)

Hope this helps.