# How to pass a Noda Time (or any third-party type) object as a parameter in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, date, service, nodatime

I have a service which uses Noda Time types (`LocalDate` and `ZonedDateTime`) in OperationContract parameters, but when I try sending for example `LocalDate(1990,7,31)` the server receives an object with the default value (1970/1/1). No error is thrown by the client or the server.

Previously it worked well with the corresponding BCL types (`DateTimeOffset`). I understand Noda Time types may not be "known" by WCF, but I don't see how I am supposed to add them. I checked [this page in the documentation about known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx), but it does not help.

Is there any way to do this to avoid a dirty (and possibly incomplete) manual conversion/serialization from and to a BCL type?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like Jon didn't include DataContract attributes in Noda. You might need to use the [IDataContractSurrogate interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Aron! This was very helpful. I was able to create a surrogate in no(da) time using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/14/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742225/using-a-datacontractsurrogate-with-wcf-rest

Comment: NodaTime only currently supports Json.NET serialization, and only then via `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` which is not currently compiled into the main release.  You'd have to build it yourself.  I'm glad to hear you were able to get this working with DataContract surrogates. I'm interested to see your implementation.  Would be willing to post it somewhere (GitHub, GIST, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Matt, I have posted the full code with explanations here (as an answer), and on gist (easier to copy paste it at once).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Aron's suggestion, I was able to come up with an implementation of IDataContractSurrogate, which is very helpful to pass objects of non base types through WCF (not only Noda Time).

For those who are interested, here is the complete code with explanations, supporting LocalDate, LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime. The serialization method can of course be customized to meet the requirements, for example using Json.NET serialization, as my simple implementation will not serialize era/calendar information.

Alternatively, I have posted the full code on this Gist: https://gist.github.com/mayerwin/6468178.

First, the helper class that takes care of serializing/converting to base types:

```
public static class DatesExtensions {
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this LocalDate localDate) {
        return new DateTime(localDate.Year, localDate.Month, localDate.Day);
    }

    public static LocalDate ToLocalDate(this DateTime dateTime) {
        return new LocalDate(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);
    }

    public static string Serialize(this ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return LocalDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern.Format(zonedDateTime.LocalDateTime) + "@O=" + OffsetPattern.GeneralInvariantPattern.Format(zonedDateTime.Offset) + "@Z=" + zonedDateTime.Zone.Id;
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime DeserializeZonedDateTime(string value) {
        var match = ZonedDateTimeRegex.Match(value);
        if (!match.Success) throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not parse " + value);
        var dtm = LocalDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value).Value;
        var offset = OffsetPattern.GeneralInvariantPattern.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value).Value;
        var tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(match.Groups[3].Value);
        return new ZonedDateTime(dtm, tz, offset);
    }

    public static readonly Regex ZonedDateTimeRegex = new Regex(@"^(.*)@O=(.*)@Z=(.*)$");
}
```

Then a `ReplacementType` class which contains the serialized data (Serialized should only store types that are known by the WCF serializer) and can be passed over WCF:

```
public class ReplacementType {
    [DataMember(Name = "Serialized")]
    public object Serialized { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "OriginalType")]
    public string OriginalTypeFullName { get; set; }
}
```

The serialization/deserialization rules are wrapped in `Translator` generic classes to simplify adding rules to the surrogate (only one surrogate is assigned to the service endpoint so it should contain all the necessary rules):

```
public abstract class Translator {
    public abstract object Serialize(object obj);
    public abstract object Deserialize(object obj);
}

public class Translator<TOriginal, TSerialized> : Translator {
    private readonly Func<TOriginal, TSerialized> _Serialize;

    private readonly Func<TSerialized, TOriginal> _Deserialize;

    public Translator(Func<TOriginal, TSerialized> serialize, Func<TSerialized, TOriginal> deserialize) {
        this._Serialize = serialize;
        this._Deserialize = deserialize;
    }

    public override object Serialize(object obj) {
        return new ReplacementType { Serialized = this._Serialize((TOriginal)obj), OriginalTypeFullName = typeof(TOriginal).FullName };
    }

    public override object Deserialize(object obj) {
        return this._Deserialize((TSerialized)obj);
    }
}
```

Finally the surrogate class, each translation rule can be easily added in the static constructor:

```
public class CustomSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate {
    /// Type.GetType only works for the current assembly or mscorlib.dll
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> AllLoadedTypesByFullName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Distinct().GroupBy(t => t.FullName).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.First());

    public static Type GetTypeExt(string typeFullName) {
        return Type.GetType(typeFullName) ?? AllLoadedTypesByFullName[typeFullName];
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Translator> Translators;
    static CustomSurrogate() {
        Translators = new Dictionary<Type, Translator> {
            {typeof(LocalDate), new Translator<LocalDate, DateTime>(serialize: d => d.ToDateTime(), deserialize: d => d.ToLocalDate())},
            {typeof(LocalDateTime), new Translator<LocalDateTime, DateTime>(serialize:  d => d.ToDateTimeUnspecified(), deserialize: LocalDateTime.FromDateTime)},
            {typeof(ZonedDateTime), new Translator<ZonedDateTime, string> (serialize: d => d.Serialize(), deserialize: DatesExtensions.DeserializeZonedDateTime)}
        };
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type) {
        if (Translators.ContainsKey(type)) {
            type = typeof(ReplacementType);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType) {
        Translator translator;
        if (Translators.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out translator)) {
            return translator.Serialize(obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType) {
        var replacementType = obj as ReplacementType;
        if (replacementType != null) {
            var originalType = GetTypeExt(replacementType.OriginalTypeFullName);
            return Translators[originalType].Deserialize(replacementType.Serialized);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And now to use it, we define a service named `SurrogateService`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISurrogateService {
    [OperationContract]
    Tuple<LocalDate, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime> GetParams(LocalDate localDate, LocalDateTime localDateTime, ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime);
}

public class SurrogateService : ISurrogateService {
    public Tuple<LocalDate, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime> GetParams(LocalDate localDate, LocalDateTime localDateTime, ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return Tuple.Create(localDate, localDateTime, zonedDateTime);
    }
}
```

To run on a completely standalone basis with the client and server on the same machine (in a Console application), we just need to add the following code to a static class and call the function `Start`():

```
public static class SurrogateServiceTest {
    public static void DefineSurrogate(ServiceEndpoint endPoint, IDataContractSurrogate surrogate) {
        foreach (var operation in endPoint.Contract.Operations) {
            var ob = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            ob.DataContractSurrogate = surrogate;
        }
    }

    public static void Start() {
        var baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SurrogateService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISurrogateService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        var surrogate = new CustomSurrogate();
        DefineSurrogate(endpoint, surrogate);

        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISurrogateService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        DefineSurrogate(factory.Endpoint, surrogate);
        var client = factory.CreateChannel();
        var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InUtc();
        var p = client.GetParams(localDate: now.Date, localDateTime: now.LocalDateTime, zonedDateTime: now);

        if (p.Item1 == now.Date && p.Item2 == now.LocalDateTime && p.Item3 == now) {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }
        ((IClientChannel)client).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Voilà ! :)